# Google spreadsheet script - Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have a google spreadsheet designed for a specific purpose and its working fine with script in backend. I need to sell this to many users. I understand that google doesn't allow code protection.
So I an planning to make this an addon which users can install and my plan is to have code in the addon to activate the addon only with a password provided by me for their id. So that users can pay me and I can provide them a password to activate the code.

If I develop some thing like this for my income, will google script store allow me to publish my addon?

Also, as my addon is specifically for my Google spreadsheet format, will it be a problem for publishing in the store. Will Google accept this?

Comment: Have you read http://developers.google.com/apps-script/?

Comment: You should join the [Developing Add-on Group](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)  Your question is "off topic" for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The Google webstore terms of service can be [found here.](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/terms) My own recommendation would be not to make your whole addon as a paid product. Perhaps better to launch it for free first and find out if there is a market for it. Build a community of users and get their feedback on how to make it better. Then if it is wildly successful consider various approaches to monetizing your code, such as a donation button, paid for advanced features, youtube tutorials etc.